# Is there any Vim plug-in that can show the file hierarchy?

Tags: vim, macrabbit-espresso

For folks who have used the [Espresso](https://espressoapp.com/) editor, I'll love the right bar for showing the file hierarchy based on the tag nesting and open close. Is it possible in Vim?

I thought taglist was promising, but it's just too smart, it collects and categorize the class and method, but for me who want to know the file hierarchy to know the file structure need the basic feature like Espresso has.

Can taglist be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: [Tagbar](https://web.archive.org/web/20130129081104/http://majutsushi.github.com:80/tagbar/)
Anyway "Groups tags according to the scope and display them" is in the Taglist plugin's todo :D.

This might be something off topic but I prefer [Outline Unite plugin](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/h1mesuke/20101107/p1%5D) for this kind of functionality because it's integrated with Unite, so you can jump to the function you want by typing their name, and you don't have to keep the outline windows open all the time.

Comment: Tagbar is very very nice but I don't think it works with HTML which I think is one of the asker's requirements.

Comment: @tungd I use Vundle to get this plugin, But I don't know how to use it, :TagBar do not exsit.

Comment: @tungd problem solved ! I found tagbar in the bundle list, soI change the github link to the tagbar, everything works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Try NERDTree.  I don't know if you can integrate it with taglist, but it'll let you browse the file hierarchy. You can get it at [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) or on [github](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/). Then you can open it with `:NERDTree`.  An even better way to open it is to create a mapping like this

```
map <leader>t :NERDTreeToggle
```

Which, for me, toggles it with `,t`, so you can keep it out of the way when you don't need it.

Comment: I believe what his means by file hierarchy is a kind of outline, showing how HTML tags, class properties/method nesting inside each other. Check the screenshot "Navigator" [here](http://macrabbit.com/espresso/features/edit/)

Comment: Ah that makes more sense. I don't use taglist, so I assumed he actually meant files. The other answer looks good.